# Java weird out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have no idea why I'm getting out of bounds for this.

```
int[][] board = new int[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; i ++) {
        board[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are incrementing `i` in the `j` for loop.  Change

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; i ++){
```

to

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
```